# Symfony Elasticsearch combine results

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I have two tables which are indexed with Elasticsearch in my project. I have the following tables:

**Product Table:**

```
+----+----------+------+-----+------+
|Id  | category | name | sku | ean  |
+----+----------+------+-----+------+
```

**Product_stock Table**

```
+---+-----+------+--------+-------+
|id | sku |stock | vendor | price |
+---+-----+------+--------+-------+
```

Symfony config for elasticsearch

```
indexes:
    app:
            types:
                product:
                    properties:
                          type: text
                        sku:
                          type: text
                        ean_upc:
                          type: text
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\Product
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~

indexes:
    productstock:
            types:
                product_stock:
                    properties:
                        sku:
                          type: text
                        vendor:
                          type: text
                        stock:
                          type: integer
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductStock
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
```

How can I combine these two tables with Elasticsearch Into 1 table to show to enduser ?

I have this but this is just for 1 table:

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.product');
$products = $finder->find($query, '500');
```

Comment: I think you must use nested fields https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/types.md#nested-objects-in-foselasticabundle ... Elastic search has not "joins" between indexes

Comment: @SilvioQ Thats what I want to find out if it's possible to mix two tables if I search for a specific sku